# How to install NodeJS + MongoDB on ec2 Amazon server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-ec2

I don't have much knowledge about mongo and  NodeJS, and also about server set up so I might be asking something basic.

I'm trying to install MongoDB and NodeJS for school project.
In order to do so I registered to Amazon EC2 server and implemented an instance according to some tutorials I've found on line.
Using MongoDB wiki, I've installed Mongo on the server and using another Tutorial I installed NodeJS.

Just to be super clear, please see below picture who's showing the directory and MongoDB server listening:

http://s23.postimg.org/k02f747m2/mongo_Dir.jpg

After I've done that I'm trying to start using the server, I've created a simple file using the following code:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var server = new mongodb.Server('127.0.0.1', 27017, {});
var client = new mongodb.Db('exampledb', server, {w: 1});

client.open(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  client.collection('students', function(err, collection) {
    if (err) throw err;

    collection.insert(
      {
        "name": "Noam",
        "year": "2012."
      },
      {safe: true},
      function(err, documents) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Document ID is: ' + documents[0]._id);
      }
    );
  });
});
```

Now I tried to run the file and received the following error

http://s30.postimg.org/sqplfazlt/eror.jpg

Any help?

Comment: do you have mongodb module in your node_module directory ? if not try to running npm install mongodb , probably you forgot it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Tried to do it and received:      http://oi59.tinypic.com/2qtvpnb.jpg

Comment: add sudo to command : sudo npm install mongodb

Comment: Error: failed to fetch from registry: mongodb
and lot of other lines